# Parsing HTML pages using Beautiful Soup-family trees

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I am writing a parsing script that should access "img" tags in an HTML page (and I am utilizing Beautiful Soup.)
I am using the findAll method in order to access each image in the code, but I also want to access an additional piece of information. I want the the title of each image which is located in the immediate preceding "a" tag, under the href attribute.
The HTML code looks like:

```
div class="thumbinner" style="width:202px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Edmund-Hillary.web.jpg" class="image">img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Edmund-Hillary.web.jpg/200px-Edmund-Hillary.web.jpg" width="200" height="272" class="thumbimage" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.........
```

I am trying to use the parent/child methods from beautiful soup but am getting errors.
My code looks something like:

```
images= soup.findAll("img", width=true)#access all image tags
jpegtitles= images.siblings['href']
```

I figured since the "img" tag and "a" tag were both children of the "div" tag then they would be accessible by the sibling method.

Any suggestions on how I could access: href="/wiki/File:Edmund-Hillary.web.jpg"
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the image tag is after the `<a>` tag, you want to find the parent and not the sibling:

```
>>> soup.find('img', width=True).parent['href']
'/wiki/File:Edmund-Hillary.web.jpg'
```

The other problem with your code is that `findAll` returns a list, and so you can't directly call `.siblings` on it. If you have multiple images, use a loop.

Comment: But if I want them hand in hand? Meaning for each specific image tag I want the "a" tag? Is there a way to access it using the image tag such that they are linked?